# Cannot cast DataItem to DataRowView in Custom Binding Scenario

Tags: c#, data-binding, gridview

I have an object that returns an IList which I'm getting from my ObjectDataSource and binding to a Gridview.  All works fine if I just use standard binding, but I'm trying to customize my binding to set properties on a linkbutton as follows:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //  extract the link button
                LinkButton lnkViewMap = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkViewMap");

                //  grab the datarowview
               System.Data.DataRowView row = (System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

                //  set the onclientclick to fire our showMap javascript function,
                //  passing through the lat/longs
                lnkViewMap.OnClientClick = string.Format("showMap({0}, {1}); return false;", row["Lat"], row["Long"]);
            }
        }
```

My error occurs where I am casting the e.Row.DataItem to a DataRowView.  The code above is from Matt Berseth's awesome blog on Virtual Earth...which is what I am trying to implement here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in the debugger and see what type `e.Row.DataItem` actually is.

It would only be a `DataRowView` if the `DataSource` you are setting on the grid is a `DataView` or `DataTable`.  Otherwise it would be the element type of the collection.

Comment: That did it...I cast the DataItem to my element type and then accessed it's properties using the normal notation and it worked...thanks!

Comment: NP .. plus that's way better than messing around with DataRowViews!  Strongly-typed data binding FTW.